# Without installing new plug-ins, can you shrink the status bar?

Tags: geany

The bottom bar in my Geany Window, namely the status bar, seems far too big. There is a setting for hiding it, but I can't find any for shrinking it. Can it be done without having to install anything? It's a change that I'd like, but I don't feel want to bloat Geany.

Comment: It looks like it might not be possible without replacing the status bar with a different GUI element. Geany's status bar is a GTK 2 GtkStatusBar object which apparently has a fixed minimum height. Using Glade 3.8.6 (i.e. Glade for GTK 2) to edit my installed Geany's GUI resource file `/usr/share/geany/geany.glade`, I was able to increase the height of the status bar but not to decrease it. To make sure the minimum height wasn't fixed by Geany, I added a second, empty GtkStatusBar object to Geany below the original one, and it was also fixed at the same minimum height.

Comment: @DavidYockey If you're confident, feel free to post that as an answer.

Comment: Not quite that confident. Someone with more GTK-related knowledge or experience might be able to work some magic. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Geany with GTK3 (see Help->Debug Messages to find out):

there is no general fix but you can adjust the padding of status bar for Geany by creating the file `~/.config/geany/geany.css` (or wherever your Geany configuration is stored) and add the following content:

```css
statusbar {
    margin: -6px 0;
}
```

Maybe you need to tweak the value of `-6px` to fit your needs.
Note: you need to restart Geany to see the change.

General information on customizing Geany with `geany.css` can be found in the manual: https://www.geany.org/manual/#customizing-geany-s-appearance-using-gtk-css